# Could calling core.memory's GC.collect consistently make for a more consistent framerate?

Tags: garbage-collection, real-time, d, frame-rate

I'm looking into making a real time game with OpenGL and D, and I'm worried about the garbage collector. From what I'm hearing, this is a possibility:

- 10 frames run
- Garbage collector runs kicks in automatically and runs for 10ms
- 10 frames run
- Garbage collector runs kicks in automatically and runs for 10ms
- 10 frames run
- and so on

This could be bad because it causes stuttering. However, if I force the the garbage collector to run consistently, like with GC.collect, will it make my game smoother? Like so:

- 1 frame runs
- Garbage collector runs for 1-2ms
- 1 frame runs
- Garbage collector runs for 1-2ms
- 1 frame runs
- and so on

Would this approach actually work and make my framerate more consistent? I'd like to use D but if I can't make my framerate consistent then I'll have to use C++11 instead.

I realize that it might not be as efficient, but the important thing is that it will be smoother, at a more consistent framerate. I'd rather have a smoothe 30 fps than a stuttering 35 fps, if you know what I mean.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472133/turning-off-the-d-garbage-collector and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574552/d-programming-without-the-garbage-collector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but it will likely not make a dramatic difference.

The bulk of time spent in a GC cycle is the "mark" stage, where the GC visits every allocated memory block (which is known to contain pointers) transitively, from the root areas (static data, TLS, stack and registers).

There are several approaches to optimize an application's memory so that D's GC makes a smaller impact on performance:

- Use bulk allocation (allocate objects in bulk as arrays)
- Use custom allocators (std.allocator is on its way, but you could use your own or third party solutions)
- Use manual memory management, like in C++ (you can use `RefCounted` as you would use `shared_ptr`)
- Avoiding memory allocation entirely during gameplay, and preallocating everything beforehand instead
- Disabling the GC, and running collections manually when it is more convenient

Generally, I would not recommending being concerned about the GC before writing any code. D provides the tools to avoid the bulk of GC allocations. If you keep the managed heap small, GC cycles will likely not take long enough to interfere with your application's responsiveness.

Comment: +1 for the custom allocators, in a game you can make heavily use of stack allocators for stuff of each frame which is not needed the next frame, and other custom allocator schemes

Comment: I think it's important to mention that a collection can only be started by a GC operation (like allocating using the GC). If you can make sure you never use the GC during gameplay (you can still use it in load/startup phases) then the GC won't kick in.

Answer (score 4):

If you were to run the GC every frame, you still would not get a smooth run, because you could have different amounts of garbage every frame.

You're left then with two options, both of which involve turning off the GC:

- Use (and re-use) pre-allocated memory (structs, classes, arrays, whatever) so that you do not allocate during a frame, and do not need to.
- Just run and eat up memory.

For both these, you would do a `GC.disable()` before you start your frames and then a `GC.enable()` after you're finished with all your frames (at the end of the battle or whatever).

The first option is the one which most high performance games use anyway, regardless of whether they're written in a language with a GC.  They simply do not allocate or de-allocate during the main frame run.  (Which is why you get the "loading" and "unloading" before and after battles and the like, and there are usually hard limits on the number of units.)